# Using Array as Argument for a Function

Tags: php, arrays, function

Code inside Function is working, but  as  i want  to process  more  then one Url i wanted  to make it  a  function  using  a  array  to get  the  urls to process. Here is the  Code:

```
    <?php
$site = array("http://www.ihr-apotheker.de/cs1.html", "http://www.ihr-apotheker.de/cs2.html", "http://www.ihr-apotheker.de/cs3.html");

function parseNAI($sites)
  {
  foreach ($sites as $html)
    {
      $clean_one = strstr($html, '<p>');
      $clean_one_class = str_replace('<p><span class="headline">', '<p class="headline gruen"><span>', $clean_one);
      $clean_one_class_a = strip_tags($clean_one_class, '<p><span><a>');
      $clean_one_class_b = preg_replace("/\s+/", " ", $clean_one_class_a);
      $str_one = preg_replace('#(<a.*>).*?(</a>)#', '$1$2', $clean_one_class_b);
      $ausgabe_one = strip_tags($str_one, '<p>');
      echo $ausgabe_one;
    } 
  };
parseNAI($site);
?>
```

Where is my problem as  the  function stops  working at the beginning of   the foreach....
Thx in advance  for your help!

Comment: You don't need a semicolon after the function's closing curly brace. It looks like your foreach loop needs to actually load the page contents from the URL in `$html` before performing its other actions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have a feeling you are missing a step in there... maybe a `file_get_contents` or the like?  Right now you are running a bunch of string functions on the uri themselves, not the source at the uri.

Try this instead:

```
<?php
$site = array("http://www.ihr-apotheker.de/cs1.html", "http://www.ihr-apotheker.de/cs2.html", "http://www.ihr-apotheker.de/cs3.html");

function parseNAI($sites)
{
    foreach ($sites as $url)
    {
        $html = file_get_contents($url);
        $clean_one = strstr($html, '<p>');

        $clean_one_class = str_replace('<p><span class="headline">', '<p class="headline gruen"><span>', $clean_one);
        $clean_one_class_a = strip_tags($clean_one_class, '<p><span><a>');
        $clean_one_class_b = preg_replace("/\s+/", " ", $clean_one_class_a);
        $str_one = preg_replace('#(<a.*>).*?(</a>)#', '$1$2', $clean_one_class_b);
        $ausgabe_one = strip_tags($str_one, '<p>');
        echo $ausgabe_one;
    } 
};
parseNAI($site);

?>
```

Comment: Oh my god - im  so stupid!
proofe  its  too late  for  me
i thought  of  all  but  not  that  i forgot  to put  this  specific  line in......
thx!

Answer (score 0):

rather than pass an array why not loop through your array and pass each element to the function? - multiple calls to the same function...

judging by what you're function should you not be scraping the contents of eahc page rather than just the URL???

Answer (score 0):

This line returns '' because there is no p tag in your URL strings..

```
$clean_one = strstr($html, '<p>');
```

What are you trying to do?  If you're trying to get the content of those sites, use file_get_contents() or similar functions to fetch URL content.

Comment: the origin sites  are  real bad coded - but  its  free  content they  gave  me  to input into my  site - so my  intention  was  to remove  all bad  code  except  the raw  text  with some  <p>  tags.  with the  first  answer  i have  seen i missed  a line  of  code  when i  turned it into  a  function